# Cannot find logs in openstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, devstack

I recently installed open stack, and whenever I launch an instance I get an error state. To resolve this, I tried looking for the logs, however I cant seem to find the logs anywhere! (No logs in this location: http://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ops/content/logging_monitoring.html)

I tried looking for information on if logging should be enabled, but i cant seem to find anything on that either. How do I get logs for anything?

Comment: The logs should be on /var/log/_servicename_. How did you install OpenStack? Also, did you try to open the logs file as root? Last idea, did you add "verbose = True" in your conf files? Just trying a few ideas here, hope it helps

Comment: I git cloned it and then used stack.sh, however in /var/log/ there aren't any folders with service names, which is why I am confused. Let me try the verbose.